# breakdown of individual xpath selectors and results

Tags: java, xpath

Assuming the following document:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="home.htm">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="page.htm">Link to a page</a>
      <b>Bold text</b>
      <a href="page2.htm">Link to another page</a>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I run this xPath I get the result following:

```
/html/body/div/a/text() -> HomeLink to a pageLink to another page
```

I am looking for a way to reverse-engineer the results and extract the individual xPath selectors and its associate result as simple as possible. Something as:

```
/html/body/div[1]/a[1]/text() <-> Home
/html/body/div[2]/a[1]/text() <-> Link to a page
/html/body/div[2]/a[2]/text() <-> Link to another page
```

I can guess some complicate program by traversing the DOM tree or a SAX parsing but looks too complex.

Can someone figure out a simpler way to achieve this result in xPath (maybe helped by a bit of Java as well)? Basically the problem is to know each index of each tag and the associated result for each successful combination.

Thanks

Comment: Check the function `position()` it may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know java.

Here is a sample Ruby code using nokogiri gem:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML open('/tmp/input.html')
doc.xpath('//a//text()').each {|a| puts "#{a.path} -> #{a.text}" }
```